# .NET Core 2/Angular 5 Image Compression

Tags: angular, image, compression, asp.net-core-2.0

This is a very simple question. I have a simple website with a few jpeg images. I've been reading about the power of enabling g-zip on the server, and intend to do that to reduce file sizes across js/html/css files. However, I'm not entirely sure how to reduce the size of images sent over the wire. Should images be compressed manually before being loaded onto the server, or is there some compression tool that compresses images on the server when they are requested? I imagine some combination of both would be ideal, but I can't seem to find a best practice for this. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images should be ideally served as they are, they usually are and should be stored already compressed. There are various tools that help you compress images. You can do so manually with online tools such as [TinyPNG](https://tinypng.com/).

Or you can integrate image optimization into your workflow, with gulpfile and package [gulp-imagemin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-imagemin).

There are certainly ways to do that automatically on the server as well. One such example is Google PageSpeed Module, but it's only available when using Nginx/Apache as reverse proxy. [PageSpeed Image Filter Documentation](https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/reference-image-optimize)

Answer (score 1):

Most images (with the exception of BMP and SVG I think) are binary and are already compressed (unlike the javascript, html, css files), so there is probably no reason to compress them further, unless you want to reduce their quality (i.e. JPEG - lossy compression) which is probably not something you should do per every request.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a mac, I recommend using [ImageOptim](https://imageoptim.com/mac). It will hide all the details of which software to use for which image format.

Even better if you use Github, try [Shrink.sh](http://www.shrink.sh). It will create automatically detect images in your project and submit pull request with optimized version of them.